# Convert column into same format

Tags: python

I have an incident number column that I'm trying to make consistent in terms of the format that it's in. Some are printed as '15-0019651' and others are '18490531'. All I'm trying to do is remove the hyphen for the Inci_no's that have them.

When I run df.Inci_no.dtype it returns it as object.

Comment: please provide your code, current output and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

`df['incident_no'] = df['incident_no'].str.replace('-','')`

Comment: This is will convert the data type to String, maybe remaining code will break.

Comment: @ZainArshar Since some of the elements in the column contain hyphen, then they are already interpreted as ``object`` type, basically string. So, the approach proposed seems to meet the author's requirements.